# CAGR on Dynamic Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of 12 rows as follows:

[image]

For simplicity let's assume that the column is A and the values are in rows 1-12 (ignoring the first two rows).

I need to calculate the CAG, for which the formula is:

```
(end value/beginning value)^1/(# of years) -1
```

Here it would be `(38026/2402)^(0.25)-1`. The small thing is that for every column I have, the first non zero value appears in a different row number. This both affects the years # in the formula, as well as the value in the beginning period.

What formula would give me that?

Comment: Why is `1/periods#` = 0.25 with the sample data layout?

Comment: 4 years between the values

Comment: Let me see If I got this right: 1.The first non zero value will always be the denominator 2. The 2nd the numerator 3. The distance between those 2 cells  will be part of the power calculation  4. in each column there will be always 12 rows with exactly 2 non zero values. Are all those correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following data layout:

[image]

You can find:

`B1` - position of first non value with:

```
=MATCH(1,--(A1:A12<>0),0)
```

`C1` - position of last value (exluding `#REF!`) with:

```
=MATCH(9.999999E+307,A1:A12)
```

`D1` - CAGR value with:

```
=(INDEX(A1:A12,C1)/INDEX(A1:A12,B1))^(1/(C1-B1))-1
```

Or:

```
=RATE(C1-B1,,-INDEX(A1:A12,B1),INDEX(A1:A12,C1))
```

Second method was found [here](http://techtites.com/calculate-cagr-microsoft-excel/).

Comment: I actually solved it but yours is more elegant. Good job. Kudos!